# Java pow BigInteger implementation

Tags: java, cryptography, biginteger, pow, exponent

I am working on a cryptography implementation and part of the design includes the following:

( (y^a)^b / (y^c)^b ) mod p

I have the following snippet:

```
BigInteger yab = y.pow(ab.intValue());
BigInteger ycb = y.pow(cb.intValue());

BigInteger ans = (yab.divide(ycb)).mod(p);
```

It works fine for small integer. Once I replaced it with generated keys, the exponent grew so huge and I will hit the "BigInteger out of int range" error. I have tried the modPow function but the result is different.

I understand that casting it to int has its limitation. Does that means my implementation is infeasible?

Comment: Looking at your other question, you really should read up on what a modular inverse is...

Comment: Hi @Mysticial, some part of my implementation do uses modInverse. But I am not sure how it can apply in this context. Are you able to advise?

Comment: @kenAu89 You definitely picked the wrong answer: although **peter-lawrey** gave you what you wanted, it was not what you really needed to compute, as no sane cryptographer would devise a formula that allows any kind of reduction, especially that even a school kid can exercise. You should follow the advice of **mysticial** above and accept the solution by **artjom-b** below.

Comment: @AntonSamsonov hello sir. Thank you for your advice. Everything seems clearer now regarding using modular inverse for my implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the code and this will also make it faster

```
x^y / x^z = x^(y - z)
```

so

```
BigInteger yab = y.pow(ab.intValue());
BigInteger ycb = y.pow(cb.intValue());

BigInteger ans = (yab.divide(ycb)).mod(p);
```

can be simplified to

```
BigInteger yabc = y.pow((int) (ab.longValue() - cb.longValue()));
BigInteger ans = yabc.mod(p);
```

or

```
BigInteger and = y.modPow(ab.minus(cb), p);
```

Comment: Hello sir, your solutions works! since i can use the modpow function it no longer limits to the conversion to int. Thanks alot! Appreciate your advice!

Comment: Also modPow will correctly deal with negative exponents.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're doing modular arithmetic in group [image] where *n* is a prime (in your case is *n* = *p*). This means that

```
x / y
```

is not a division but a multiplication of *x* with the *y<sup>-1</sup>* (modular inverse of *y*).

Good thing is that the [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class provides such a method:

```
BigInteger ans = yab.multiply(ycb.modInverse(p)).mod(p);
```

where `yab` and `ycb` can be efficiently computed without overflow (assuming `ab` is the product of `a` and `b`):

```
BigInteger yab = y.modPow(ab, p);
BigInteger ycb = y.modPow(cb, p);
```